# How to join two or more DAX tables in DAX studio

Tags: powerbi, dax, dmv

I am looking for a way to do a LEFT JOIN like in SQL but with DAX. I have two tables employee table and department table. I want to join two DMV tables(views) in DAX studio.

I have tried using the evaluate function
EVALUATE NATURALINNERJOIN($SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_COLUMN,$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS)
but getting syntax error.

[DMV Dax studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBEAn.png)

Comment: You can achieve the same in the query editor (M query) instead of dax.

Comment: How to open M editor in DAX studio?

Comment: You can't, Sorry I assumed that you are working in power bi

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to join in dax is having the tables related. This article should help you manage joins.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/

Comment: can we join the DMV tables? Please check the screenshot attached above.

Comment: I don't think you can. Actually DMV works different than dax. You may be able to check data but you can't query it with dax the way you want. Maybe you can find a dmv table with the result you are looking for.
The only way I'm thinking is to get data from SSAS and join it in power bi like this post:
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/02/01/analysing-power-bi-dmv-queries-in-power-bi-desktop/

Comment: can I use the $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_COLUMN and $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS  (DMV tables) to join in SSAS. Please guide me how to join the DMV's in SSAS.

Comment: I just answer you. You can't from the same model. The only similar thing I have ever seen is the link to the blog y have posted you from crossjoin uk. You can't do it from another way

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem and solved it; you may already have, but thought I pass it along.

You had it right just missed one expression, the EVALUATE function.

EVALUATE
NATURALINNERJOIN($SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_COLUMN,$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS)

Until I added "evaluate" I could not get DAX Studio to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

There are steps of doing this, so first I export data from these dMV tables in a csv format (Change result to file in DAX Studio) then add these files in powerbi. I added a empty string because of data lineage issue.

[image]