# SQL Equivalent in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a SQL query and I've tried to build an equivalent DAX query but not able to do it.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```
select table1.column1, table1.column2, table1.column3 
from table1 join table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column1
where table1.column2 = table2.column2;
```

Comment: Instead of WHERE, why not use AND for a compound join? What does 'not able' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Edit question to show your failed attempt and provide sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302264/how-to-join-two-or-more-dax-tables-in-dax-studio and https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/#:~:text=In%20DAX%20there%20are%20two%20ways%20you%20can,a%20result%20equivalent%20to%20certain%20types%20of%20JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your model ( current relationship between tables).
If Table1 has relationship to table2 on (table1.column1 = table2.column1); then you can just add columns to Table Visualization.

Create additional object:

```
test = If( table1[column2] = table2[column2], 1, 0 )
```

put this in filters pane and select 1 as argument.